# Stop loop and fade in area that is hovered on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of javascript/jquery I am trying to figure out. What I have already is three boxes that the content fades in and out and loops through the three and repeats. What I am trying to do is when "box x" is hovered over the loop fades out and stops never to start again, and the box that is hovered on, the content below the box fades in and stays... unless another box is hovered over, then the content that faded in from the other hovered box will fade out and the new box that was hovered on, the content that coincides with that box fades in and stays fade in, and so forth.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/q0htx0no/

javascript/jquery

```
var infoboxes = $(".count p");
var counter = 0;

function rotate() {
    $(infoboxes[counter]).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(infoboxes[counter]).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                counter = counter < infoboxes.length - 1 ? counter + 1 : 0;
                rotate();
            })
        }, 1000);
    });
}

$(function() { 
    rotate(); 
});
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your fiddle is missing

Comment: Sorry about that @General_Twyckenham it is there now

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q0htx0no/2/) have a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a global variable (a 'flag') that would indicate if the rotation should be stopped. Once a box has been hovered over, it should set hovered to True and should fade in that specific box.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use a global variable.  Something like this:

```
var infoboxes = $(".count p");
var counter = 0;
var goAhead = true;

function rotate() {
    $(infoboxes[counter]).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(infoboxes[counter]).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                counter = counter < infoboxes.length - 1 ? counter + 1 : 0;
                checkRotate();
            })
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function checkRotate() {
    if (goAhead) { rotate(); }
}

$('.about').on('mouseover', function() {
    goAhead = false;
    var index = $(this).index();
    var boxesToClear = $(infoboxes).filter(function(i) { return i !== index; });
    $(boxesToClear).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(infoboxes[index]).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});

checkRotate();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q0htx0no/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. It can probably be improved.

http://jsfiddle.net/vbt67x0h/2/

```
var infoboxes = $(".count p");
var counter = 0;
var isrotating = false;

function rotate(){
 isrotating = true;
 $(infoboxes[counter]).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
 counter = counter < infoboxes.length - 1 ? counter + 1 : 0;
}

//immediately stop rotate and hide all
function stoprotate(){
    clearInterval(tmrrotate);
    isrotating = false;
    for(var x=0;x<infoboxes.length;x++){
     $(infoboxes[x]).stop();
     $(infoboxes[x]).hide();
    }
}

rotate();

//rotate every 3 seconds, 1 to fadein, 1 to pause, 1 to fadeout
var tmrrotate = setInterval(function() {
    rotate();
  }, 3000); 

$(".about").on('mouseover', function() {
    if(isrotating){stoprotate()}
    $(infoboxes[$(this).index()]).fadeIn(1000);
    })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(infoboxes[$(this).index()]).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a timed array:

```
var arTimer = [];
```

and push all timers into that array, `clearTimeout` on hover and show only hovered index:

```
var infoboxes = $(".count p");
var counter = 0;
var arTimer = [];

function rotate() {
    $(infoboxes[counter]).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        arTimer.push(setTimeout(function() {
            $(infoboxes[counter]).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                counter = counter < infoboxes.length - 1 ? counter + 1 : 0;
                rotate();
            })
        }, 1000));
    });
}

function cleararTimer(){
    for (var i = 0; i < arTimer.length; i++) {
        clearTimeout(arTimer[i]);
    }
}

$(function() { 
    rotate();
    $('.about').on('mouseover', function(){
        cleararTimer();
        var hovered = $(this).index();
        $('.count p').not(':eq('+hovered+')').fadeOut(1000);
        $('.count p:eq('+hovered+')').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/q0htx0no/2/)